# How to prevent TradingView to overlay the parameters of an Indicator on chart?

Tags: pine-script

My indicator uses two many parameters, variables and TradingView display all of them in a line, disturbing the chart. Most of them are just used in math, not displayed, there's no reason to read their values.

How to tell TradingView not to do it? (Perhaps it's not Pine Script but I didn't find a solution in TradingView's UI.)
[image: Parameters disturb the chart.]

Comment: You can hide `Indicator arguments` or/and `Indicator Values` in the `Chart settings` -> `Status Line`.  In the future there will be more flexible setting to hide and show plot values in Pine.